# mysqli_fetch_all raising undefined function error in PHP 7.3

Tags: php, mysqli, mysqlnd

I'm trying to get my website working publicly (my host is Namecheap), but I'm having some trouble with my sign-in-page. After I submit my log-in-form `500 Internal Server Error` appears. I checked my error logs and found the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_fetch_all()
```

My PHP version is 7.3 and I have mysqlnd on. Here is the line that raises the error:

```
$user_data = mysqli_fetch_all($query_result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)[0];
```

`$query result` is the value of this expression:

```
mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `email` = '$email';");
```

The website works flawlessly locally using XAMPP.

Comment: Think about moving to PDO https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php

Comment: @Dharman Thanks for informing me. I wasn't aware of ```mysqli_real_escape_string``` not being enough necessary.